# remove [] from output values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I'm pulling data from google trends and the output values come out as follows:

```
                 date value
0 2017-01-01 03:00:00  [65]
1 2017-01-01 03:01:00  [66]
2 2017-01-01 03:02:00  [77]
3 2017-01-01 03:03:00  [64]
4 2017-01-01 03:04:00  [94]
```

I've trimmed what I don't need. My issue is I need to remove the brackets and make the calue column an int. I've tried the following:

```
result['value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).replace('[', '').replace(']', '')))
```

But I get the same output either way. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].explode()
```

Output:

```
                  date value
0 2017-01-01  03:00:00    65
1 2017-01-01  03:01:00    66
2 2017-01-01  03:02:00    77
3 2017-01-01  03:03:00    64
4 2017-01-01  03:04:00    94
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
df['value'] = df['value'].str[0]
```